# What is the difference between Philips Essential LED bulb range & their normal LED bulbs?

Tags: lighting, led, bulb, light

I have come across two ranges from Philips for their LED bulb ranges, there is the 'Essential' range, which is the budget value range, & then there is the normal 'Philips' LED bulbs range. The price difference between the two is substantial (upto 50% price difference) & in some cases, the 'Essential' range is more efficient, having a higher lumens/ watt. I have been purchasing the 'Essential' range so far.

So, I wonder what is the difference between the two ranges? After reading about CRI from my [question here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/126683/led-bulbs-which-measure-is-the-best-indicator-of-efficiency), I am wondering whether the difference between the two is in light quality (CRI) and / or other non-obvious variables.

Comment: It’s hard to say precisely, however there are two characteristics that aren’t “measured” by the lighting industry that consumers are demanding.  One is dimming range when used with traditional dimmers.  The other is the color of light when dimmed (consumers like that orangey warm light an incandescent bulb makes when dimmed.  Overtime lighting manufacturers have added products to their lines..  Now some manufactures like Phillips have cheaper economy versions and pricier bulbs with the features consumers want— but the changing characteristics aren’t things previously measured by the industry.

Comment: What is the advertised service life of each bulb?

Comment: The life is as per normal, between 20,000 hrs to 50,000 hrs.